# Trying to run tesseract project on Java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Trying to run tesseract project  on Java, but have some weird exception with bytes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File image = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/file.tiff");
    BufferedImage ima = ImageIO.read(image);
    ITesseract ocrEngine = new Tesseract();
    ocrEngine.setDatapath("/Users/user/Downloads/Tess4J/tessdata");
    try {
        String text = ocrEngine.doOCR(ima);
        System.out.println(text);

    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And have this error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xverify:none
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/var/folders/fd/7093p25178n6_b8kp7qlfdhr0000gn/T/jna--1680431912/jna3169952727692915541.tmp, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/fd/7093p25178n6_b8kp7qlfdhr0000gn/T/jna--1680431912/jna3169952727692915541.tmp: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at autotest.OCR.main(OCR.java:23)
```

Comment: Add the native code, your path may be wrong